# iOS-App-Developer: Get number of downloaded updates

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Is it possible to see how many users of my app have downloaded the latest patch?

Comment: you can see all the data in your iTunes connect. Are you asking a way to get all that data?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about app sales, not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in `Itunes Connect`. But you just can see the total number of updates you cannot per version. A trick is check the number of updates then release your app update and in the follow days see the number of the new updates.

See an example with `Itunes Connect App`.

[image: Itunes Connect]

Comment: Ah, great! =) Thank you very much!